# (Libgdx and Rube Box2d) merge worlds

Tags: java, android, box2d, libgdx

Well well well, I use the RubeLoader to load my rube files on libgdx.

However I noticed that I can only load ONE json file

Code :

```
loader = new RubeSceneLoader();
scene = loader.loadScene(Gdx.files.internal("test.json"));
World mWorld ;
mWorld = scene.getWorld();
```

As you can see, If I want to load another json file, it will destroy the previous one because of this line :

```
mWorld = scene.getWorld();
```

So my problem is : **how can I load multiple json file or how can I merge differents world into one ?**

Thanks you in advance for your answers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I checked the sourcecode of RubeLoader and libGDX and cannot see why it should break the first world. I checked it myself after that (not very extensive, but I think I covered your usecase) and it worked fine for me.

Multiple Worlds are supported by Box2D, LibGDX and the RubeLoader. But of course you need multiple instances of the World.

```
loader1 = new RubeSceneLoader();
scene1 = loader1.loadScene(Gdx.files.internal("XXXX.json"));
World mWorld1 = scene1.getWorld();

loader2 = new RubeSceneLoader();
scene2 = loader2.loadScene(Gdx.files.internal("ABCD.json"));
World mWorld2 = scene2.getWorld();
```

Now you have two `Worlds` and they should both work fine, but merging them wouldn't be easy at this point. Because you would have to recreate everything from `mWorld2` in `mWorld1` or the other way around. I'd suggest you to programmatically merge the two JSON files (libGDX has already the necessary JSON tools, but you might use other small json libraries like [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/)) and then load this merged scene. That should be a lot easier than merging two `Worlds`.

Edit:
If you need to merge the `Worlds` not right from the start, but after a while, the easiest would be to modify the `RubeWorldSerializer`. Specifically this part:

```
World world = new World(gravity, allowSleep);
world.setAutoClearForces(autoClearForces);
world.setContinuousPhysics(continuousPhysics);
world.setWarmStarting(warmStarting);
```

Try to find a way to input your already existing `mWorld1` here instead and when loading the second scene, all `Bodies` and `Joints` should automatically be added to this `World`, instead of a completely new one.

Edit2:
A quick idea how it could be done:

Add this to the `RubeWorldSerializer`: `public static World mergeWorld;`.

Change the World initialization like this:

```
World world;
if (RubeWorldSerializer.mergeWorld == null) {
    world = new World(gravity, allowSleep);
    world.setAutoClearForces(autoClearForces);
    world.setContinuousPhysics(continuousPhysics);
    world.setWarmStarting(warmStarting);
} else {
    world = RubeWorldSerializer.mergeWorld;
}
```

Now Your loading would have to look like this:

```
loader1 = new RubeSceneLoader();
scene1 = loader1.loadScene(Gdx.files.internal("XXXX.json"));
World mWorld1 = scene1.getWorld();

RubeWorldSerializer.mergeWorld = mWorld1; // this is important in between your loading.

loader2 = new RubeSceneLoader();
scene2 = loader2.loadScene(Gdx.files.internal("ABCD.json"));
World mWorld2 = scene2.getWorld(); // in theory mWorld2 should be the same like mWorld1 now, and it should be both worlds merged
```

Comment: I want first thanks you for your answer, but my test results that when I load the scene it destroy the previous world (previous world is the world that was in the same world variable that I used to load the RubeScene). I know I can load differents scene in different worlds but it's useless for my case, however thanks you for your Jackson libraries but I was wondering for merging differents RubeScenes and thus load them at differents moments. Anyway, I will look what I can take from this Jackson libraries

Comment: You said that I must recreate everything from mWorld2 in mWorld1. If you could show me the way to do it, I ll appreciate, no matter how long it is, I can turn it into a function after, for easy use.

Comment: I just added an edit to my answer giving you a hint how you could do it, though I don't have time right now to work out a fully functioning version myself.

Comment: Okay, last edit for now. Not sure it would work, but that's how I would try it.

Comment: I've never thought doing it that way, I can't try it by now but I will asap, I really appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the libGDX loader, in the C++ version of the loader the main loading function can be easily modified to take an existing world as a parameter. If the existing world is not null, it will be used instead of making a new one. Otherwise, a new world will be created as normal.

Before (pseudocode!):

```
World loadWorld( File f ) {
    World w = <make a new world>
    //load the scene into w
    return w;
}
```

After:

```
World loadWorld( File f, World w ) {
    if ( w == null )
        w = <make a new world>
    //load the scene into w
    return w;
}
```

The same idea could probably be done in many other languages.

Comment: @noone 's answer solved my problem, if you are really the iforce2d who made rube, you should give this code to the guy who made the libgdx loader to improve it. Thanks you

Comment: "The same idea could probably be done in many other languages."... hihi, yeah. It's basically what I offered him in my answer, for the libGDX specific loader :)